# How to verify that Windows application respects proxy settings?

Tags: windows, proxy, testing

I want to solve the following problem:

I have a Windows desktop application which does a number of things that requires internet access. I want my application to be able to use a proxy. This is simple enough to code, but my problem is how to TEST it. Specifically, I want to test that all internet traffic from my application goes through the proxy (when one is configured).

Part of the problem is that I need a working proxy. I've covered that in this other question: [How to set up Docker proxy (e.g. Squid) to send all traffic through?](https://serverfault.com/questions/984839/how-to-set-up-docker-proxy-e-g-squid-to-send-all-traffic-through)

But another problem is: Even when I have a working proxy, how do I verify that the application uses it?

So far the best I have been able to do is a "negative" test:

1. Set Windows proxy (start menu -> Proxy settings) to something invalid, e.g. a random server that is not at all set up to work as a proxy.
2. Run the application and try to use the features that require internet access.
3. Verify that the application fails since internet access is effectively blocked by the bad "proxy".

This is better than nothing, but I also want to do a "positive" test. I imagine that I need to do this:

1. Set Windows proxy to point to a valid, functioning proxy.
2. Somehow block all internet traffic from my computer that does NOT go through the proxy.
3. Run the application and try to use the features that require internet access.
4. Verify that the application works.

I don't know how to accomplish step 2. Can anyone advise me?

Comment: Why don't you check your Squid access and cache logs? And/ or block every outbound traffic from your machine to anything else except the proxy with your firewall.

Comment: By "block every outbound traffic from your machine to anything else except the proxy with your firewall" do you mean block all outgoing ports except the port that my proxy is running on?

Comment: Yes, for example. Could prove difficult, depending on your docker config, but it was just an example. Easier to check your logs. (Or set your application to use one specific sourceport and block everything except sourceport -> proxy-port)